# While loop in main thread is getting stuck when using std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, mpi, infinite-loop, stdthread

I have a simple C++ code to test and understand threading. The code has the main thread + a secondary thread. 
The secondary updates the value of a variable which the main thread loop depends on. When I add a print statement inside the main loop the program finishes successfully, but when I remove this print statement it goes into an infinite loop. 
This is the code that I'm using, and the print statement that I'm referring to is print statement 2

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
std::mutex mu;
int num;
using namespace std;

void WorkerFunction()
{
    bool work = true;
    while(work)
    {
            mu.lock();
            num --;
            mu.unlock();

            if(num == 1)
               work = false;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    bool work = true;
    num = 10;
    int numRanks, myRank, provided;
    MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED, &provided);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numRanks);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myRank);

    std::thread workThread (WorkerFunction);
    //print statement 1
    cerr<<"Rank "<<myRank<<" Started workThread \n";

     int mult = 0;
     while(work)
     {
          mult += mult * num;
         //print statement 2
         if(myRank == 0) cerr<<"num = "<<num<<"\n";
         if(num == 1)
           work = false;
      }
   if(work == false)
      workThread.join();

   //print statement 3
   cerr<<"Rank "<<myRank<<" Done with both threads \n";

   MPI_Finalize();

 };
```

This is the output I get when I have print statement 2

```
mpirun -np 4 ./Testing
Rank 0 Started workThread 
num = 10
num = 10
num = 10
num = 10
num = 10
num = 10
num = 10
num = 10
num = 10
num = 10
num = 10
num = 10
num = 10
Rank 1 Started workThread 
Rank 0 Done with both threads 
Rank 1 Done with both threads 
Rank 2 Started workThread 
Rank 3 Started workThread 
Rank 2 Done with both threads 
Rank 3 Done with both threads
```

If I comment out that print statement then it goes into an infinte loop and this is the output I get

```
mpirun -np 4 ./Testing
Rank 0 Started workThread 
Rank 0 Done with both threads 
Rank 1 Started workThread 
Rank 2 Started workThread 
Rank 3 Started workThread 
Rank 2 Done with both threads 
Rank 3 Done with both threads
```

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior.  You nedd to use the mutex in you main function as well when you access `num`.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver! Do I also need to use mutex before starting the thread? For example when initializing `num`?

Comment: I don't believe you need to, since starting a thread should be a synchronization point but I'm not 100% sure on that though.  It would be better to be safe than sorry, or just initialize `num` when you declare it.  You wouldn't need it then.

Comment: Don’t you have to declare `volatile int num;`?

Comment: There is a synchronization point before entry into the thread function (`WorkerFunction` in this code), so he assignment to `num` in `main` is okay.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet.— `volatile` has no role in threading in the C++ standard. Some compilers might do something special with it, but that would be an extension, not standard.

Comment: if I comment out the second print statement, the program works just fine if compiled with `-O0` but hangs with `-O2` (I am using gcc 8.2.0). If I declare `volatile int num;`, then the program always works regardless the optimization level.

Comment: @PeteBecker I am not a C++ programmer, so I will not challenge you on the standard. That being said, `volatile` is documented at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv. If it has no role in C++, then my logical conclusion is that all global variables must be treated as `volatile` by the compiler. It definitely favors correctness but at the expense of performance, which I find very surprising.

Comment: As a side note, MPI has nothing to do with this and the same behavior can be observed with a non-MPI program.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet — I said that `volatile` has no role **in threading** in the C++ standard, not that it has no role at all in C++.

Comment: @PeteBecker sure, but let's go back to the initial question. Do you consider the use of `volatile` as a correct fix or as a side-effect that happens to do the trick with a given compiler? In both cases, feel free to suggest a better/correct fix.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet — if your compiler documents that it does what you want with `volatile`, then that ought to work with that compiler. Nevertheless, `volatile` is not the right answer to thread synchronization issues in portable code, and the answer to your question “don’t you have to declare `volatile int num;` is “no”. The correct fix has already been given: use the mutex correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning MPI, I haven't any experience. (I used it decades ago, and I'm sure that fact is completely worthless.) However, OP claimed

> I have a simple C++ code to test and understand threading.

Considering, that multiprocessing (with `MPI`) as well as multithreading (with `std::thread`) are complicated topics on its own, I would separate the topics first, and try to put them together after having gained some experience in each of them.

So, I elaborate a bit about the multithreading (which I feel able to).

---

First sample is a revised version of OPs code (all references to `MPI` removed):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

std::mutex mtxNum;
int num;

const std::chrono::milliseconds delay(100);

void WorkerFunction()
{
  for (bool work = true; work; std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay)) {
    int num_;
    mtxNum.lock();
    num_ = --num;
    mtxNum.unlock();
    work = num_ != 1;
  }
}

int main()
{
  num = 10;
  std::thread workThread(&WorkerFunction);
  int mult = 0;
  for (bool work = true; work; std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay)) {
    int num_;
    mtxNum.lock();
    num_ = num;
    mtxNum.unlock();
    std::cout << "num: " << num_ << '\n';
    mult += mult * num_;
    work = num_ != 1;
  }
  if (workThread.joinable()) workThread.join();
  std::cout << "Both threads done.\n";
}
```

Output:

```
num: 10
num: 8
num: 7
num: 6
num: 5
num: 4
num: 3
num: 2
num: 2
num: 1
Both threads done.
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60f6c0682067b0c8)

**Notes:**

1. While multithreading is running, and variable `num` is shared, and variable `num` is modified in at least one thread, every access should be put into a [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) (a pair of mutex lock and unlock).
2. The critical section should always be kept as short as possible. (Only one thread can pass the critical section at one time. Hence, it introduces re-serialization which consumes speed-up intended by concurrency.) I introduced a local variable `num_` in each thread to copy current value of shared variable and to use it after critical section in the respective thread.<sup>*</sup>
3. I added a `sleep_for()` to both threads for better illustration. Without, I got

   ```
   num: 10
   num: 1
   Both threads done.
   ```

   which I found somehow boring.
4. The output skips `num == 9` and prints `num == 2` twice. (This may look differently in other runs.) The reason is that the threads work asynchronously by definition. (The equal delay of 100 milliseconds in both threads is no reliable synchronization.) The OS is responsible to wake a thread if nothing (like e.g. the locked mutex) prevents this. It is free to suspend the thread at any time.

Concerning `mtxNum.lock()`/`mtxNum.unlock()`: Imagine that the critical section contains something more complicated than a simple `--num;` which may throw an exception. If an exception is thrown, the `mtxNum.unlock()` is skipped, and a [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) is produced preventing any thread to proceed.

For this, the `std` library provides a nice and handy tool: [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

std::mutex mtxNum;
int num;

const std::chrono::milliseconds delay(100);

void WorkerFunction()
{
  for (bool work = true; work; std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay)) {
    int num_;
    { std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtxNum); // does the mtxNum.lock()
      num_ = --num;
    } // destructor of lock does the mtxNum.unlock()
    work = num_ != 1;
  }
}

int main()
{
  num = 10;
  std::thread workThread(&WorkerFunction);
  int mult = 0;
  for (bool work = true; work; std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay)) {
    int num_;
    { std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtxNum); // does the mtxNum.lock()
      num_ = num;
    } // destructor of lock does the mtxNum.unlock()
    std::cout << "num: " << num_ << '\n';
    mult += mult * num_;
    work = num_ != 1;
  }
  if (workThread.joinable()) workThread.join();
  std::cout << "Both threads done.\n";
}
```

Output:

```
num: 10
num: 8
num: 7
num: 6
num: 5
num: 4
num: 3
num: 2
num: 1
Both threads done.
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b3ee5d9c09c98e0)

The trick with `std::lock_guard` is that the destructor unlocks the mutex in any case, even if an exception is thrown inside of critical section.

May be, I'm a bit paranoid but it annoys me that non-guarded access to a shared variable may happen by accident without being noticed in any debugging session nor any compiler diagnostics.<sup>**</sup> Hence, it might be worth to hide the shared variable into a class where access is only possible with locking it. For this, I introduced `Shared` in the sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

template <typename T>
class Shared {
  public:
    struct Lock {
      Shared &shared;
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock;
      Lock(Shared &shared): shared(shared), lock(shared._mtx) { }
      ~Lock() = default;
      Lock(const Lock&) = delete;
      Lock& operator=(const Lock&) = delete;

      const T& get() const { return shared._value; }
      T& get() { return shared._value; }
    };
  private:
    std::mutex _mtx;
    T _value;
  public:
    Shared() = default;
    explicit Shared(T &&value): _value(std::move(value)) { }
    ~Shared() = default;
    Shared(const Shared&) = delete;
    Shared& operator=(const Shared&) = delete;
};

typedef Shared<int> SharedInt;
SharedInt shNum(10);

const std::chrono::milliseconds delay(100);

void WorkerFunction()
{
  for (bool work = true; work; std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay)) {
    int num_;
    { SharedInt::Lock lock(shNum);
      num_ = --lock.get();
    }
    work = num_ != 1;
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::thread workThread(&WorkerFunction);
  int mult = 0;
  for (bool work = true; work; std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay)) {
    int num_;
    { const SharedInt::Lock lock(shNum);
      num_ = lock.get();
    }
    std::cout << "num: " << num_ << '\n';
    mult += mult * num_;
    work = num_ != 1;
  }
  if (workThread.joinable()) workThread.join();
  std::cout << "Both threads done.\n";
}
```

Output: similar as before.

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4de1c56096c869cf)

The trick is that a reference to shared value can be retrieved from a `Shared::Lock` instance → i.e. while it is locked. Even if the reference is stored:

```
    { SharedInt::Lock lock(shNum);
      int &num = lock.get();
      num_ = --num;
    }
```

The lifetime of `int &num` just ends before the lifetime of `SharedInt::Lock lock(shNum);`.

Of course, one could get a pointer to `num` to use it outside of scope but I would consider this as sabotage.

---

Another thing, I would like to mention is [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic):

> The atomic library provides components for fine-grained atomic operations allowing for lockless concurrent programming. Each atomic operation is indivisible with regards to any other atomic operation that involves the same object.

While a mutex may be subject of OS kernel functions, an atomic access might be done exploiting CPU features without the necessity to enter the kernel. (This might provide speed-up as well as result in less usage of OS resources.)

Even better, if there is no H/W support for the resp. type available it falls back to an implementation based on *mutexes or other locking operations* (according to the Notes in [`std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free)):

> All atomic types except for std::atomic_flag may be implemented using mutexes or other locking operations, rather than using the lock-free atomic CPU instructions. Atomic types are also allowed to be sometimes lock-free, e.g. if only aligned memory accesses are naturally atomic on a given architecture, misaligned objects of the same type have to use locks.

The modified sample with `std::atomic`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>

std::atomic<int> num;

const std::chrono::milliseconds delay(100);

void WorkerFunction()
{
  for (bool work = true; work; std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay)) {
    work = --num != 1;
  }
}

int main()
{
  num = 10;
  std::thread workThread(&WorkerFunction);
  int mult = 0;
  for (bool work = true; work; std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay)) {
    const int num_ = num;
    std::cout << "num: " << num_ << '\n';
    mult += mult * num_;
    work = num_ != 1;
  }
  if (workThread.joinable()) workThread.join();
  std::cout << "Both threads done.\n";
}
```

Output:

```
num: 10
num: 8
num: 7
num: 7
num: 5
num: 4
num: 3
num: 3
num: 1
Both threads done.
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b76a1b3666725a62)

---

<sup>*</sup> I brooded a while over the `WorkingThread()`. If it's the only thread which modifies `num`, the read access to `num` (in `WorkingThread()`) outside critical section should be safe – I believe. However, at least, for the sake of maintainability I wouldn't do so.

<sup>**</sup> According to my personal experience, such errors occur rarely (or  never) in debug sessions but in the first 180 seconds of a presentation to a customer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer!! This is very useful and it is exactly what I was looking for to understand threading. Thanks again!!