# Does it require mutex locking for arguments to be passed to pthread?

Tags: c++, struct, arguments, pthreads, mutex

I have a function that will be called multiple times and this function will create a new pthread every it gets called. And i need to pass some arguments using struct to the pthread every it gets created.

Does it require to have a mutex locking for those struct (in the function that create the pthread) whenever passing the arguments to the pthread?

Please advise.

Comment: [mcve] please .

Comment: You need mutexes only when same data is accessed from multiple threads. It is not clear from your example if you use same data or not.

Comment: You don't need to lock arguments which are passed to a thread. Starting a thread is a sufficient sync. for the starting/started thread. You have to lock variables which are used concurrently in at least two threads if at least one thread modifies them. (This might help also: [SO: While loop in main thread is getting stuck when using std::thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57177535/7478597).)

Comment: Consider using `std::thread` instead of pthread: a) Its standard, b) Its portable.

Comment: Thanks for all the advise. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> i need to pass some arguments using struct to the pthread every it gets created.

I suppose you must mean something along these lines:

```
struct args {
    int arg1;
    double arg2;
    char *arg3;
};

void *thread_func(void *p) {
    struct args *args = p;

    // ... do something with args ...

    return some_value;
}

// ...

void foo() {
    pthread_t tid;
    struct args *args;
    // ...
    args = some_expression;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_func, args);
    // ...
}
```

> Does it require to have a mutex locking for those struct (in the
>   function that create the pthread) whenever passing the arguments to
>   the pthread?

Using a mutex in function `foo()` alone would do no good for anyone.  Mutexes provide for synchronization only between two different pieces of code that both successfully lock the same one (necessarily at different times).

More generally, launching a new thread synchronizes all actions in the new thread with all actions preceding the thread launch in the parent thread.  In particular, the new thread can read the contents of the argument structure without any special measures and without thereby causing a data race, **provided that** no other thread modifies that structure, and the structure's lifetime does not expire.  The new thread can even modify the argument structure without a data race, **provided that** no other thread accesses it at all, and its lifetime does not expire.

There are definitely still ways you could get into trouble, however, as the above provisos suggest.  Appropriate bi- or multi-lateral use of mutexes would resolve some such issues, but not others.  For example, if the args structure presented to the new thread is in fact an automatic variable of the function that launches the thread, and the thread in fact accesses the structure via the provided pointer, then there is a potential data race between the new thread's access(es) to the structure and the end of its lifetime.  For example,

```
void foo() {
    pthread_t tid;
    struct args args;  // an automatic variable
    // ...
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_func, &args);
    // ...
    // the lifetime of args ends when control reaches here
}
```

In such a case, you need to ensure that the new thread performs all its accesses to the args structure before `foo()` (running in a different thread) returns.  A mutex (alone) cannot do that for you -- instead, you want a condition variable (which must be used together with a mutex), or a semaphore, or one of a variety of other alternatives.