# Threads keep running and executing commands

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I want to make mutilple threads in C++ that keep running and waiting for main thread commands and execute them accordingly. Here's the code I wrote and I know it causes the `spinning` problem. So the question is how can I let the CPU stop running the worker thread untill I change the command. I know there are `future and promise`, but they seem not suitable for this situation.

[edit] I'm a C++ noob and this is so complicated! If anyone can share me some tutorials or libraries to solve this, that would be much appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

class empty
{
public:
    empty() {}
    void work1()
    {
        std::cout << "work1" << std::endl;
    }
    void work2()
    {
        std::cout << "work2" << std::endl;
    }
};

enum CMD
{
    WAIT,
    CMD1,
    CMD2,
    DONE
};

void worker(CMD &cmd, empty &e)
{
    std::mutex mutex;
    while (cmd != DONE)
    {
        switch (cmd) {
            case WAIT:
                break;
            case CMD1:
                e.work1();      // excute cmd 1
                mutex.lock();
                cmd = WAIT;     // change cmd to WAIT
                mutex.unlock();
                break;
            case CMD2:
                e.work2();
                mutex.lock();
                cmd = WAIT;
                mutex.unlock();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    empty e1 = empty();
    empty e2 = empty();

    CMD cmd = WAIT;

    // mutilple thread working on mutilple empty object
    std::thread wokerThread1 = std::thread(worker, std::ref(cmd), std::ref(e1));
    std::thread wokerThread2 = std::thread(worker, std::ref(cmd), std::ref(e2));

    ... //some other code

    cmd = CMD1;

    ... 

    cmd = CMD2;

    ... 

    cmd = CMD1;

    ... 

    cmd = DONE;

    wokerThread1.join();
    wokerThread2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `std::condition_variable`.

Comment: You should consider using an `std::atomic`. This smells like data races all over the place.

Comment: Also, for mutexes to work, they have to be shared accross threads. As you have it right now, each thread gets its own mutex, so there is no synchronization happening.

Comment: You could use pipes to send command to the thread which will block (put read inside while(true)) if the pipe is empty and will awake when it's not.

Comment: In addition to @Frank: Every access to a shared variable has to be mutex guarded, and, of course, the same variable at best always with the same mutex. This includes the "main" thread as well. All occurrences of `cmd = `... in `main()` are un-guarded -> U.B.

Comment: Another answer [SO: While loop in main thread is getting stuck when using std::thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57177535/7478597)

Comment: With some minor typos but, in general, (IMHO) not that bad: [C++11 Multithreading](https://thispointer.com//c-11-multithreading-part-1-three-different-ways-to-create-threads/) (with 10 parts).

Comment: @Frank I see where the problem is, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you could use `Observers` with async operations here. The idea is that your main control thread updates the `CMD` for all interested observers and then the observers execute particular operation depending on the `CMD`. In this example I made "update" operation blocking (previous job must be finished before you start a new one) and returning `void`. However, you might think about other possibilities, like returning `false` if previous operation is still ongoing.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

enum CMD
{
  WAIT,
  CMD1,
  CMD2,
  DONE
};

class SomeSystem
{
public:
  SomeSystem() = default;
  void work1()
  {
    // let's pretend this work takes some time
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    std::cout << "work1" << std::endl;
  }
  void work2()
  {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    std::cout << "work2" << std::endl;
  }
};

class CmdObserver
{
public:
  CmdObserver(std::shared_ptr<SomeSystem> system, int id): system_(system), id_(id)
  {
    std::cout << "observer[" << id_ << "] CTor" << std::endl;
  }
  void update(CMD cmd)
  {
    if (work_.valid() && work_.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::timeout)
    {
      std::cout << "observer[" << id_ << "] blocking until previous work is finished" << std::endl;
    }
    work_ = std::async(std::launch::async, [this, cmd]() { doTheJob(cmd); });
  }

private:
  void doTheJob(CMD cmd)
  {
    std::cout << "observer[" << id_ << "] going to execute cmd " << cmd << std::endl;
    switch (cmd)
    {
      case CMD1: system_->work1(); break;
      case CMD2: system_->work2(); break;
      default: std::cout << cmd << std::endl;
    }
  }
  std::shared_ptr<SomeSystem> system_;
  // id_ is just for demonstration purposes
  int id_;
  std::future<void> work_;
};

int main()
{
  int observerId = 0;
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeSystem> > systems({
    std::make_shared<SomeSystem>(),
    std::make_shared<SomeSystem>(),
    std::make_shared<SomeSystem>(),
    std::make_shared<SomeSystem>(),
    std::make_shared<SomeSystem>()
  });
  std::vector<CmdObserver> observers;
  for (auto system : systems)
  {
    observers.push_back(CmdObserver(system, observerId));
    observerId++;
  }
  for (auto& observer : observers)
  {
    observer.update(CMD1);
  }
  for (auto& observer : observers)
  {
    observer.update(CMD2);
  }
  // let's pretend we do some long operation here
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  for (auto& observer : observers)
  {
    observer.update(CMD1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer works exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

One why of doing this is by using a `concurrent_bounded_queue`.  You can use [TBB's](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506201) implementation for this or implement it using `std::queue` and `std::condition_variable`.

Implementation using only `std`;

```
#include <queue>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex g_m;
std::condition_variable g_cv;

enum CMD
{
  CMD1,
  CMD2,
  DONE
};

void push_cmd(std::queue<CMD>& tasks, CMD cmd) {
  const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_m);
  tasks.push(cmd);
  g_cv.notify_one();
}

CMD pop_cmd(std::queue<CMD>& tasks) {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(g_m);
  g_cv.wait(lk, [&tasks]{ return !tasks.empty(); });

  CMD cmd = tasks.front();
  tasks.pop();
  return cmd;
}

void execute_cmd(int cmd) {
  std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": cmd [" << cmd << "]" << std::endl;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(cmd));
}

void worker(std::queue<CMD>& tasks) {
  CMD cmd = pop_cmd(tasks);
  while (true)
  {
    switch (cmd) {
      case CMD1:
        execute_cmd(1);
        break;
      case CMD2:
        execute_cmd(2);
        break;
      case DONE:
      default:
        return;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  std::queue<CMD> tasks;

  std::thread wokerThread1 = std::thread(worker, std::ref(tasks));
  std::thread wokerThread2 = std::thread(worker, std::ref(tasks));

  push_cmd(tasks, CMD1);
  push_cmd(tasks, CMD2);

  // push `DONE` for each worker
  push_cmd(tasks, DONE);
  push_cmd(tasks, DONE);

  wokerThread1.join();
  wokerThread2.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Implementation using `tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue`;

```
#include <tbb/concurrent_queue.h>

void worker(tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue<CMD>& tasks) {
  while (true) {
    CMD cmd;
    tasks.pop(cmd);
    switch (cmd) {
    case CMD1:
      // excute cmd 1
      break;
    case CMD2:
      // excute cmd 2
      break;
    case DONE:
    default:
      return;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue<CMD> tasks;

  std::thread wokerThread1 = std::thread(worker, std::ref(tasks));
  std::thread wokerThread2 = std::thread(worker, std::ref(tasks));

  ...
  tasks.push(CMD1);
  tasks.push(CMD2);
  ...
}
```

Note you want to run the same task multiple times you can create a `Worker` that wraps everything up as follows;

```
#include <chrono>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>

enum CMD
{
  CMD1,
  CMD2,
  DONE
};

void executeCmd(int cmd) {
  printf("exec %u: cmd[%d]\n", std::this_thread::get_id(), cmd);
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(cmd));
}

class Worker
{
public:
  Worker()
    : _thread(std::thread(&Worker::work, this))
  {
  }

  void pushCmd(CMD cmd) {
    printf("push %u: cmd[%d]\n", std::this_thread::get_id(), cmd);
    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_m);
    _tasks.push(cmd);
    _cv.notify_one();
  }

  void finish() {
    pushCmd(DONE);
    _thread.join();
  }

private:
  std::thread _thread;
  std::mutex _m;
  std::queue<CMD> _tasks;
  std::condition_variable _cv;

  CMD popCmd() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(_m);
    _cv.wait(lk, [&]{ return !_tasks.empty(); });

    CMD cmd = _tasks.front();
    printf("pop  %u: cmd[%d]\n", std::this_thread::get_id(), cmd);
    _tasks.pop();
    return cmd;
  }

  void work() {
    while (true) {
      CMD cmd = popCmd();
      switch (cmd) {
        case CMD1:
          executeCmd(1);
          break;
        case CMD2:
          executeCmd(2);
          break;
        case DONE:
        default:
          return;
      }
    }
  }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  Worker w1, w2;
  w1.pushCmd(CMD1);
  w2.pushCmd(CMD1);

  w1.pushCmd(CMD2);
  w2.pushCmd(CMD2);

  w1.finish();
  w2.finish();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: TBB might appear as MT Swiss-Army-Knife. However, for learning I would recommend to fix the code with what `std` C++ provides. IMHO, it's worth to get experience about what happens "under the hood".

Comment: Don't you need to put the `DONE` command twice (i.e. one for each thread)?

Comment: @scheff you can always write your own concurrent_thread_queue :P

Comment: _you can always write your own concurrent_thread_queue_ This is what I already did (and swapping of buffers via atomic pointer variables and inter-thread communication via atomic flags and... - cannot remember what else.) :-)

Comment: @bertubezz Thanks for your answer! Let me try to see if it works.

Comment: @Scheff Appreciate your help! I think this question can't be solved by some easy implementations, I will have a long way to go to learn these concepts.

Comment: @bertubezz Sorry if I didn't make it clear, but what I want to do is that I need both (or mutiple) threads to do the the same task in parallel while I can change the task when I want, not one thread do one task and the other do another task. they will take in different data. Do l need to use mutilple queues (one queue for one thread) to do that?

Comment: @bertubezz please reviewed my change to your code, I add a while loop in worker, It works great now, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are a c++ noob, just make sure you are not making any of these mistakes "https://www.acodersjourney.com/top-20-cplusplus-multithreading-mistakes/"

Comment: Great, now I can double check with your link.